# Opacity and transparency

Tags: pstricks, transparency

I found some discussions about the opacity parameter in pstricks, but I still can't make it work. Here is my tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add} 

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
    \psset{fillstyle=solid}
    \psline[linecolor=blue,linewidth=12pt](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \psframe[fillcolor=red,opacity=0.5](-1,-1)(1,1)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

I compile it on Ubuntu using:

```
latex opacity.tex
dvips opacity.dvi
```

but in the PS file, there is no transparency.

What should I do to see the picture with the transparency effect?

Comment: As far as I know, `PostScript` does not know of transparency. Try to make a standalone `.eps` file from your picture/diagram and convert it `.pdf` then with `epstopdf` or something similar.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer how can I make an eps file?

Comment: Just add `ps2pdf opacity.ps` to the sequence of commands. This makes transparency visible in a PDF viewer.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi: See my 'answer' below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the document with `xelatex` or `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`. PostScript itself cannot show transparency effects. You have to use a PDF output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks} 
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
    \psline[linecolor=blue,linewidth=12pt](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red,opacity=0.5](-1,-1)(1,1)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Needs `ps2pdf -dNOSAFER <file>.ps`

Answer (score 3):

This is rather the workflow than a true answer, but only for desired output as `.pdf` or as standalone `.eps` file.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add} 
\usepackage{pst-eps}


\begin{document}

\begin{TeXtoEPS}

\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
    \psset{fillstyle=solid}
    \psline[linecolor=blue,linewidth=12pt](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \psframe[fillcolor=red,opacity=0.5](-1,-1)(1,1)
\end{pspicture}

\end{TeXtoEPS}

\end{document}
```

Run

> latex foo.tex
>
> dvips -E -o foo.eps foo.dvi
>
> epstopdf foo.eps

Comment: Using `pst-eps` is obsolet.

Comment: @Herbert: Is there a new version/new pstricks package for this feature?

Comment: no, there is no replacement. One can use `xelatex` or `auto-pst-pdf` or `pst2pdf`. No need for creating such single eps files.